# Calculation of a Gravity Resonance Keyhole

Tags: gravity, orbital-motion, newtonian-gravity, resonance, celestial-mechanics

Can anyone describe the mathematics behind the calculation of a [resonance keyhole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_keyhole) (for a two-body model)?  It seems like the size and position of the keyhole should be a function only of mass and relative velocity, but I'm having difficulty deriving a formulaic solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a two-body system would have a gravitational keyhole: you need to change the angular momentum of one object relative to its orbit with the other, in order to generate the possibility of a "future collision". The only way you can do that is with a non-central force, which I believe implies the presence of a third body.